# Remove all phones from Google Directory User

Tags: rest, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I am attempting to remove all phones from a Google Directory User, using the [Admin Directory API directory_v1](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users) > directory.users.update. 
I am sending the following request body:

```
{
 "phones": []
}
```

but this seems to have no effect.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it to null:

```
{
 “phones”:null
}
```

See the note all the way at the bottom of the API documentation you linked to in the ‘update’ section.